# Есть метод Fire нужно чтобы при вызове метода воспроизводился звук, не могу понять как лучше это реализовать, помогите!)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сижу ломаю голову, вызвать по нажатию кнопки могу, но было бы правильнее вызывать вместе с методом Fire

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SpaceShooter
{
    public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [SerializeField] private TurretMode m_Mode;
    public TurretMode Mode => m_Mode;

    [SerializeField] private TurretProperties m_TurretProperties;

    private float m_RefireTimer;

    public bool CanFire => m_RefireTimer <= 0;

    private Ship m_Ship;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_Ship = transform.root.GetComponent<Ship>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (m_RefireTimer > 0)
            m_RefireTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Public API
    public void Fire()
    {
        if (m_TurretProperties == null) return;

        if (m_RefireTimer > 0) return;

        Projectile projectile = Instantiate(m_TurretProperties.ProjectilePrefab).GetComponent<Projectile>();
        projectile.transform.position = transform.position;
        projectile.transform.up = transform.up;

        m_RefireTimer = m_TurretProperties.RateOfFire;

        {
            //SFX
        }
    }

    public void AssignLoadout(TurretProperties props)
    {
        if (m_Mode != props.Mode) return;

        m_RefireTimer = 0;
        m_TurretProperties = props;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего не понял, этот код работает или нет?

Answer (score 0):

На камере есть (если нет то сделай) AudioListener, если стреляет гг, то туда же на камеру можно прикрепить AudioSource и им воспроизводить звук.
Прикрепи в него свой звук и делай что то типо

GetComponent < AudioListener > ().Play();

AudioSource вобще крепи туда от куда должен быть звук, чтоб направление тоже играло роль.
см. документацию по AudioSource
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html